# Gitlab - Merged branch not marked as merged

Tags: gitlab, git-merge

Sorry for this "how to" question, however I really couldn't find anything in the doc, nor on the Web.

Let's take the following scenario:

1. I have a branch called "main"
2. From the "main" branch, I create a new one called "f1" (using the GUI)
3. I do some changes on the "f1" branch, and push them.
4. From the GUI, I create a new merge request to mnerges changes done on "f1" into "main".
5. From the GUI, I merge the merge request.

then, when I list branches from the GUI, I would have expected to see my "f1" branch marked as "merged", but that's not the case ...

Am I missing anthing obvious?

Comment: Have you **UN**checked the **'Delete source branch when merge request is accepted.'** option? If so, the source branch will NOT get deleted and still be operational.

Comment: Take a look at your Repository Branch Graph, the gitlab graph is really good. If there are no commits on f1 newer than the merge commit into main, it should be marked as merged, yes.

Comment: What is "the GUI", GitLab? Have you performed a real merge or are you using "squash merges" (which are not real merges at all)?